# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConstants' of null, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to run my [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native) [Expo](https://github.com/expo/expo) app, but I am facing this error:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConstants' of null, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

I tried to add "jsEngine": "hermes" to my *app.json* file, but I am still getting that error.

Comment: Do you have an error on the clean project?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to the JavaScript engine being used by your React Native Expo app. Hermes is a JavaScript engine optimized for running React Native apps, and it's the default engine in Expo.

Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:

1. Clear Cache:
   Try clearing the Metro bundler cache and the watchman watch-list. You can do this by running the following commands in your project directory:

   ```bash
   watchman watch-del-all
   rm -rf node_modules
   rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
   npm cache clean --force
   npm install
   ```

   Then, try running your app again.
2. Check Dependencies:
   Make sure your app's dependencies are up to date. Run the following command to update all dependencies in your project:

   ```bash
   npm update
   ```

   Additionally, check for any deprecated or incompatible dependencies in your `package.json` and update them as needed.
3. Verify Project Structure:
   Ensure that you are running Metro from the correct project directory. You should be in the root directory of your React Native Expo project when you run the `npm start` or `expo start` command.
4. Check for Module Errors:
   The "Invariant Violation" error often indicates a problem with one of your JavaScript modules. Review your code for any issues or missing imports. Also, check if you have correctly called `AppRegistry.registerComponent` in your entry file (usually `index.js`).
5. Downgrade Hermes:
   If you still encounter issues with Hermes, you can try downgrading to the older version by adding the following to your `app.json`:

   ```json
   "hermes": {
     "enabled": true,
     "commandUnlink": "node node_modules/hermes-engine/unlink"
   }
   ```

   This might help if there is an issue with the version of Hermes being used.
6. Verify Node and npm:
   Make sure you are using compatible versions of Node.js and npm. Check the required versions for your Expo and React Native versions in your project's documentation and ensure you have them installed.
7. Check Environment Variables:
   Ensure that you don't have any conflicting environment variables that could affect your app's behavior. Check for any environment variables related to your JavaScript engine settings.
8. Check for Other Errors:
   Review your project for any other errors in the code, and inspect the console output for more specific error messages that might give you additional clues about what's causing the problem.

If you've tried all of these steps and are still experiencing the issue, please provide more information about your project, such as your `package.json` file, any additional error messages, and the structure of your project, so I can offer more specific assistance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you vet this content beforehand. Also see the [Help](/help/ai-policy). We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!